# 2D logical matrix from vector of coordinates (Basic matlab)

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, matrix

I have a 2D vector which contains the coordinates which I want to represent as True or one in a matrix with dimensions nxm. Can I build this matrix without a loop?

Currently I am doing this:

```
points = [(1,1), (30, 20), (8,7)]
grid = zeros(n,m);

for i = 1:length(points)
    grid(points(i,1),points(i,2))=1;
end
```

Thanks a lot I'm newbie in matlab and I couldn't find the answer so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assignment to points is syntactically incorrect, it should be:

```
points=[1,30,8;1,20,7];
```

The solution to you problem lies in converting subscripts to linear indices with `sub2ind`:

```
grid(sub2ind(size(grid),points(1,:),points(2,:)))=1
```

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using a sparse matrix if the number of coordinates (`length(points)`) is much smaller (<10%) than `n*m`. This will make better use of memory and save you time.

```
points=[1,30,8;1,20,7];
grid = sparse(points(1,:), points(2,:), 1, n ,m);
```